# Google TV support for Flash Access

Tags: flash, google-tv

I am currently testing some Google TV devices (Sony NSZ-GT1 and NSZ-GS7).

I would like clarification regarding whether the Flash plugin provided with Google Chrome on these devices supports Flash Access or not.

According to the [Flash Access FAQ](http://www.adobe.com/products/adobe-access/faq.html), "Adobe Access will work with Adobe Flash Player 10.1 or later". Given that the version of Flash included on these devices is a 10.1/10.2 hybrid, I was hoping that Flash Access would work.

However, I carried out various tests and I was not able to get it working.

For the first test I used the Flash Access test site, specifically http://drmtest2.adobe.com/AccessPlayer/player.swf (player.html did not load the Flash application unfortunately)

For both devices, I got the same result - when pressing the play icon in the SVP, 'stream state' reported 'playing' and 'DRM protected' reported 'no'. The video did not play.

Additionally, for both devices, when pressing 'Load DRM Metadata' in the TVP, I received an 'Error #1009'.

The SVP reported the Flash version as 10.2.164.128 for the NSZ-GT1, and 10.2.164.113 for the NSZ-GS7.

For the second test, I used a locally built & locally hosted OSMF sample player, version 1.5, configured with the example video from the Flash Access test site.

As a reference I first tried a desktop PC browser flash plugin, and in this case I was presented with a prompt for the username and password; after entering these, the video played successfully.

However, when I attempted this from the Chrome browser on both devices, although the OSMF player loaded I was never presented with the prompt for the username and password.

Since there is no debug Flash player for Google TV, I was unable to investigate further with the device.

Any clarification or insight into support for Flash Access on Google TV would be appreciated.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Google TV was initially launched quite a while ago, Adobe had produced a doc for Flash optimization on Google TV:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/devices/articles/video_content_tv.html

where they listed Flash Access as one of the many DRM solutions so it was on the roadmap for the Flash 10.1 or 10.2 on Google TV.

Unfortunately Adobe's support on Android platform like Google TV is not ideal and Flash Access was never implemented.  Developers will be better served to look for other (e.g. Android) DRM solutions on Google TV.